# Stale Lucene index when using multiple machines

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I've got a Java/Hibernate/MySQL application up and running, and it works very nicely.

Recently I've been using Lucene (Hibernate Search) to speed up the searching and avoid round trips to the database by using projection. That works great too, except that **the index gets stale when the application gets used on multiple machines**. Lucene does a good job of updating the local index when changes are made locally, but it can't see changes from other machines.

Currently, I am:

- reindexing in full once a week
- updating a "last modified" time on all records, and updating the local index at start time based on anything modified since last indexing

But this doesn't work for deletions. If something gets deleted on one machine, it still turns up in searches on other machines.

Is there a 'standard' way to deal with this? I can think of a few options, none of which excite me:

1. reindex in full every night (still stale during the day, though)
2. maintain a table of deleted records so that I can use it to update locally
3. perform a round trip to the db at startup time to find all entries in the index but not in the db
4. add some sort of trigger to the db to record something somewhere when something gets deleted (this would work for updates as well as deletions)

Hard to believe this is a new problem, but I couldn't find any convincing answers.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You make it seem like the replication to other systems is automagic, but it is not is it? You have some home-grown logic to update a local index based on a last modified time which is done by each instance of the application (with each its own unique lucene index). But that of course won't work for deletions.

Comment: @Gimby, thank you. But I wasn't suggesting it ought to happen automatically. The behaviour I'm getting is exactly what I'd have expected; I just wondered if there was a standard way of addressing it.

Comment: I'll make your problem worse: if you connect with MySQL workbench and delete a record by hand then ALL your indexes are stale. That's your basic problem; how to deal with index items which are removed from the database outside of the control of your application instance. IMO the situation you have created (one database, multiple instances, multiple indexes) is very non-standard in itself making the problem a beast to solve.

Comment: I would probably architecturally change the way the search works; not using Hibernate search but just fetching IDs from a lucene search and using those IDs to get a list of results from the database using an IN clause. The IDs may be stale, but the database won't care and just return what is actually there.

Comment: Hmm, this does seem to defeat the point of projections, though. The point is to avoid a round trip to the database. Maybe the better option is to perform the projection search to propagate the list (including the occasional possibly deleted entry), and then, in the background, do as you suggest and perform the database query to find out what's missing, and remove anything from the list that shouldn't be there.